# Regex issue in python: try to detect `column` datatype(digits)

Tags: python, regex

I want to distinquish strings like

```
`citizen_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
`container_group` int(10) NOT NULL,
```

from strings like

```
PRIMARY KEY (`citizen_group`,`container_group`),
KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)
```

Therefor I've created this regex

```
`?\w+`?\s\w+\(d+(,\s?\d+)?\)
   ^

*\w+`*   : string, wrapped in ` is possible.                `column`
\s       : followed by a space                       
\w+      : followed by one or more characters                real
\(d+     : followd by ( with one or more digits              (10
(,\s?\d)?: followed by 0 or 1 , with digits                  ,3
\)       : end with a )                                      )
```

But this regex selects not only to first 2 strings, but also the last

```
KEY `fk_containergroup_readeraccess` (`container_group`)
```

Can someone tell me why this is? And how I need to modify the regex so that it selects only the first two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with this program:

```
import re, sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.search(r'`?\w+`?\s\w+\(\d+(,\s?\d+)?\)', line)
    if match:
        print match.group(0)
```

(Note that you're missing the '\' in '\d' immediately following the open parenthesis; I fixed that in this test.)

It matches your first two examples and does not match your second two examples, so I believe it's working as you intended it.

Comment: Weird.. A regex tester give the same result as yours. But still my code gives 3 results back...

Comment: I just mentioned that the regex does is job as expected. I don't where I went wrong from my side, but I'm glad to see it works now. Thnx